# I want to call joomla componet view on header load

Tags: joomla

Please Help Me.

I want to call joomla component view on header load.
ex. In wordpress add any function in header by using add_action('wp_head','function_name') hook.

Please tell me about joomla action hooks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very generic question and there is no simple answer, but you can start from here: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

Comment: He is right, you want a plugin for this. So write a plugin (https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) and in the plugin write whatever you want it to do in a function like `onContentBeforeDisplay(){// do something}`, this hooks it to an event. Then zip the plugin and install it on your website. It's way easier then it sounds. After it's installed you can just edit the file, it resides in /plugins/WHATEVERYOUCHOSEINSTEPONE